# Как добавить под-столбцы в table

Tags: html, css

у меня состоялся вопрос по написанию сетки.

макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у меня вопрос как прописать такую верстку table ?

или может лучше сделать это на div ?

Comment: А зачем спрашивать, когда можно заглянуть в инспектор кода и посмотреть?

Comment: это макет сделаный в figma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос просто , просто сделал таблицу на div .